# How can I optimize this code by using SENDER?

Tags: delphi, optimization, sender

I have a form that contains 16 TCheckBox and 32 TEditBox.
Every 2 TEditBox en-ability is depending of the checkBox state.
so I uses this code which is too long:

```
//T1
procedure TOFAddForm.T1Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin
     Q1.Enabled:=T1.Checked;
     P1.Enabled:=T1.Checked; 
     Q1.OnChange(Sender);
end;

.  
.
.

//T16
procedure TOFAddForm.T16Click(Sender: TObject); 
begin
     Q16.Enabled:=T16.Checked;
     P16.Enabled:=T16.Checked;
     Q1.OnChange(Sender);
end;`
```

I used this code but nothing happen:

```
procedure TOFAddForm.T1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Q, P: TEdit;
begin
     with  Sender as TCheckBox do begin
           Q.Name:='Q'+copy(Name,1,2);
           P.Name:='P'+Copy(Name,1,2);
           Q.Enabled:=Checked;
           P.Enabled:=Checked;
     end;
     Q1.OnChange(Sender);
end;
```

thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all the checkboxes and edits are consistently named, you can add this OnClick event to all checkboxes:

```
procedure TOFAddForm.TClick(Sender: TObject);
var 
  C: TCheckBox;
  Q, P: TEdit;
  N: string;
begin
  C := Sender as TCheckBox;
  N := Copy(C.Name, 2, Length(C.Name));
  Q := FindComponent('Q' + N) as TEdit;
  P := FindComponent('P' + N) as TEdit;
  Q.Enabled := C.Checked;
  P.Enabled := C.Checked;
  Q.OnChange(Sender);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you GolezTrol.
that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: don't forget to accept as answer, it will help others and it will show your gratitude towards GolezTrol

Comment: You could omit the second parameter to Copy because the default is "to the end of the source". Apart from that: Your solution works but using FindComponent always makes me feel dirty. I usually go for an array of records and use the checkbox' Tag property for the index. (oops, Remy beat me to that). Not "pure" either.

Comment: Sure.. It's not my preferred choice either. Usually, when you got these number of controls, you create them dynamically too. It might be more convenient to write a compound component, or just a simple class that holds the controls together and handles their events. But for this question, I thought it'd be better to choose a simple solution that builds on the code that already exists. Baby steps. :)

Comment: @dummzeuch, you were wrong about `Copy` b.t.w. The third parameter is obligatory (at least in D2007 and before). I could have used `LeftStr`, but that is a newer function than `Copy`. Since I don't know the Delphi version of the OP, I prefer to use `Copy` in examples like this.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Delphi 2007 allows omitting the 3rd parameter to copy. (I am not sure about earlier versions though.)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you store the `TEdit` pointers into an array and then use the `TCheckBox.Tag` property as an index into the array, eg:

```
var
  Edits: array[0..15, 0..1] of TEdit;

procedure TOFAddForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  K: Integer;
begin
  for k := 0 to 15 do
  begin
    Edits[k, 0] := FindComponent('Q' + IntToStr(k+1)) as TEdit;
    Edits[k, 1] := FindComponent('P' + IntToStr(k+1)) as TEdit;
    (FindComponent('T' + IntToStr(k+1)) as TCheckBox).Tag := k;
end;

procedure TOFAddForm.T1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Sender as TCheckBox do
  begin
    Edits[Tag, 0].Enabled := Checked;
    Edits[Tag, 1].Enabled := Checked;
    Edits[Tag, 0].OnChange(Sender);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise in cases like this to create the controls yourself. In the OnCreate event handler, call `TEdit.Create(Self)`, store the object reference in a data structure you manage yourself, e.g. a dynamic array, set properties like `Parent`, `SetBounds` and eventhandlers, and look-up `Sender` in your collection of object references (optionally depending on the value of `Tag`), this is almost always more performant than using `FindComponent`.

Added bonusses are you can alter the number of repeating controls easily (even make it dynamic at run-time!) and the dfm-code (which is embedded into the final executable) contains less almost-identical repeating data.